# FlatList calling twice

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have this code

```
class Home extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        dataSource: []
    }
    this._handleRenderItem = this._handleRenderItem.bind(this);
    this._keyExtractor = this._keyExtractor.bind(this);
  }

  componentDidMount() {

    let success = (response) => {
        this.setState({ dataSource: response.data });
    };

    let error = (err) => {
        console.log(err.response);
    };

    listarProdutos(success, error);
  }

  _keyExtractor = (item, index) => item._id;

  _handleRenderItem = (produto) => {
    return (
        <ItemAtualizado item={produto.item} />
    );
  }

  render() {
    return (
        <Container style={styles.container}>
            <Content>
                <Card>
                    <CardItem style={{ flexDirection: 'column' }}>
                        <Text style={{ color: '#323232' }}>Produtos atualizados recentemente</Text>
                        <View style={{ width: '100%' }}>
                            <FlatList
                                showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
                                data={this.state.dataSource}
                                keyExtractor={this._keyExtractor}
                                renderItem={this._handleRenderItem}
                            />
                        </View>
                    </CardItem>
                </Card>
            </Content>
        </Container>
    );
  }
}

export default Home;
```

The function `_handleRenderItem()` is being called twice and I can't find the reason. The first time the values inside my `<ItemAtualizado />` are empty, but the second was an object.

[image]

Comment: There's probably something wrong with your state handling that's causing the re-render.

Comment: would be helpful if you could create a reproducible code section in codesandbox.io

Comment: Why you're binding the _handleRenderItem & _keyExtractor? Please remove it and use only in flatlist

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is normal RN behavior. At first, when the component is created you have an empty DataSource ([]) so the FlatList is rendered with that.

After that, componentDidMount triggers and loads the updated data, which updates the DataSource.

Then, you update the state with the setState which triggers a re render to update the FlatList.

All normal here. If you want to try, load the datasource in the constructor and remove the loading in the componentDidMount. It should only trigger once.

Comment: I've changed the datasource call from componentDidMount to the constructor and still the same issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51365912/flatlist-renderitem-is-called-multiple-times

Answer (score 3):

If you want to control render actions, you can use shouldComponentUpdate method.

For example:

`shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState){
if(this.state.friends.length === nextState.friends.lenght)
return false;
}`

it will break render if friends count not change.

Answer (score 0):

I recreated the issue in this snack. https://snack.expo.io/B1KoX-EUN - I confirmed you can use shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState) to diff this.state or this.props and return true/false - https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#shouldcomponentupdate docs say this callback should be used only for optimization which is what we're doing here.